# Same data structure with different behaviors when using struct

Tags: c++, oop, memory, vector, struct

I have the following struct

```
    struct myStruct
    {
        // other stuff
        std::vector< myDataType > v_Data;
    };
```

Let's suppose I declare this struct as

```
   myStruct a;
```

and then try to push some data into v_Data. If I try to do it like this

```
   for(int i = 0; i < some_size; ++i)
       a.v_Data.push_back(something);
```

the program gets quite slow (to the point where it gets unresponsive and I have to kill the process) and memory consumption goes way up. However, if I do it like this

```
   std::vector< myDataType > tmp;
   for(int i = 0; i < some_size; ++i)
       tmp.push_back(something);
   a.v_Data = tmp;
```

then it works. I'm clueless as to why this happens, since the latter method clearly consumes more memory than the former.
Could someone please clarify this for me?

[EDIT]

As Maxim suggested in the comment section below, clearing the container before inserting into it solved the problem. So the code should be

```
   a.v_Data.clear();
   for(int i = 0; i < some_size; ++i)
       a.v_Data.push_back(something);
```

Comment: I can't see anything in the snippets you've shown that would cause a problem.  Provide a more complete code block.

Comment: You may like to clear the container before inserting into it to mimic what happens when you insert into the new container.

Comment: Thank you, Maxim. I cleared the container before inserting into it and now the program works fine. Do you have any thoughts on why this is necessary?

Comment: @pfreire can you edit the post with this update (add the code that you changes) ?

Comment: @Kobi Done. Thank you.

Comment: @pfreire try to print the size and capacity of the vector before the call to clear(). One thing that can happen is some memory corruption of your vector member. You have a comment saying "other stuff" maybe something is altering the vector internal structure which caused it to malfunction. when you clear it, you reset the size and things can start working again.